# In React, calling state twice, but second one always one step behind?

Tags: reactjs

In React, onButtonClick method updates state on currentIndex properly, but not on the currentText. If you check out the two console logs, you'll see that currentText lags behind one. How can I fix it in the same setState call? Does it have to do with React being asynchronous?

```
// dependencies
import React from 'react';
// local files
import './App.css';

const sections = [
  {
    title: 'Section 1',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
  },
  {
    title: 'Section 2',
    content: 'Cupiditate tenetur aliquam necessitatibus id distinctio quas nihil ipsam nisi modi!',
  },
  {
    title: 'Section 3',
    content: 'Animi amet cumque sint cupiditate officia ab voluptatibus libero optio et?',
  },
]

class App extends React.Component {
  // state
  state = {
    currentIndex: 0,
    currentText: ''
  };

  // event handlers
  onButtonClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: index,
      currentText: this.state.currentIndex
    }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.currentIndex);
      console.log(this.state.currentText);
    });
  }

  // helpers
  renderButtons() {
    return sections.map((item, index) => (
      <li key={item.title}>
        <button onClick={() => this.onButtonClick(index)}>{item.title}</button>
      </li>
    ));
  }

  renderContent() {
    return this.state.currentText;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.renderButtons()}
        </ul>
        <p>{this.renderContent()}</p>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default App;
```

Comment: `this.state.currentIndex` won't update immediately, so you'll have the old value still. Also are you meaning to set the `currentText` to an `int`?

Comment: By the principle of "single source of truth" your should not even store `currentText` to state. You should always calculate it dynamically from `state.currentIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
  onButtonClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: index,
      currentText: index
    }, function() {
      console.log(this.state.currentIndex);
      console.log(this.state.currentText);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
onButtonClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      ....
      currentText: sections[index].title, // update text also when selected
    }, function() {
      .....
    });
  }
```